# No option to boot into windows now I've installed El Capitan

Tags: macos, bootcamp

I have just upgraded to El Capitan from Yosemite.
Previously when holding down the option key I had the option to boot into Windows as I had installed this using Boot Camp. Now it doesn't give me that option.

After installing El Capitan I used the partition tool in Disk Utility to create some free space (the idea being that I would download Mini Tool partition wizard once back in Windows and get some more space). The Bootcamp partition seems to be there as you can see in the screenshot pictures but it just doesn't give me that option of booting into Windows when holding the alt key at start up anymore!

I changed the start up disk to Bootcamp (Windows) on start up but came up with this message "No Bootable device - insert boot disk and press any key." When press alt key can still only select Macintosh HD. It's Windows 7 and all the installers still seem to be there when I select the bootcamp disk.

Tried turning off the System Integrity Protection (SIP) as recommended by @DavidAnderson but when back in El Capitan it still didn't give me the option to 'first aid' the disk.
Here's what it currently looks like in Disk Utility...

[image]
[image]

Comment: Just says 'a whole disk needs to be specified'

Comment: Returns too many characters to reply here, is there anything in particular you would be looking for? It states that the partition map appears to be okay and everything seems to be verified! Shame I can't post an image or paste what it says!

Comment: No nothing like that everything seems to be okay. This is the last few lines if any help..Newest transaction commit checkpoint is valid
Load and verify Segment Cleaning
The volume 7A9DB9FA-0380-4BEE-9585-EB429DB2BC6D appears to be OK
Storage system check exit code is 0
The partition map appears to be OK
Finished partition map verification on disk0

Comment: No joy, thanks for trying though. Think I might just have to erase Bootcamp and install again

Comment: @DavidAnderson apologies. I've removed my comments lest they mislead anyone.

Comment: Windows 7 must be booted using a BIOS/MBR boot method. Inserting a partition caused the BOOTCAMP partition to be 5th partition. Normally, the MBR table only holds the first 4 partitions. Since the BOOTCAMP partition is no longer in the MBR partition table, you are not going to be able to boot Windows.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply David. So am I right in thinking that creating the new untitled partition means that booting into Windows now won't be possible? I suppose the best bet will be to erase the Bootcamp partition and do a fresh installation of Windows as I didn't really have anything on it anyway luckily (this time allocating more space)! The only thing I'm not sure about is whether it will let me use the same license key again!

Comment: I am not notified you posted a comment, unless you include an @David in your comment.

Answer (score 1):

[This guide](http://nerdr.com/bootcamp-partition-lost-repairing-mac-partitions) will help you fix the problem. I had a similar issue on mine. Make sure to back up your entire disk (both partitions) before making any changes though. *No joke.* Believe me, it's important. Buy an external drive if you don't have any place to back it up. (When people used to warn me to take backups, I didn't listen, and I once lost 6 months of data because of that.)

Please also see [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/210730/68458) to find out how to turn off SIP protection in El Capitan. Without turning this off it won't be possible to repair the Master Boot Record.

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.

Comment: Thanks @klanomath. +1 . I would normally do that, but it's a very long guide, and it won't be of much benefit to AD/SO for me to copy and past it here. But I completely agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

You can have up to two shared partitions between Windows and OS X. The problem is that you have to install Windows and the shared partitions before any OS X partitions.

[image: 555]

In the above image, Windows 10 is installed on Shark, Yosemite on Steelhead and El Capitan on Steelhead2. The partitions occupied by Shark2 and FREEDOS2011 are shared NTFS and FAT32 volumes, respectively. (Yes, I have a working DOS on my Mac.) Also, each OS X has a hidden recovery partition and there are 2 hidden EFI partitions for a total of 9 partitions. (The second EFI partition has [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) installed.) The remaining 100 GB of available space used to be occupied by Ubuntu Linux.

The output from `diskutil list` is given below.

```
Steelhead:~ davidanderson$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:       Microsoft Basic Data Shark                   202.0 GB   disk0s2
   3:       Microsoft Basic Data Shark2                  202.0 GB   disk0s3
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data FREEDOS2011             50.0 GB    disk0s4
   5:                  Apple_HFS Steelhead               245.1 GB   disk0s5
   6:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s6
   7:                  Apple_HFS Steelhead2              198.9 GB   disk0s7
   8:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s8
   9:                        EFI REFIND                  134.2 MB   disk0s9
```

So it is possible to have shared partitions, but this requires either reinstalling OS X or doing a backup followed by a restore of OS X.

The other way to share is to have the Windows and shared partitions follow OS X. You then have to use the [`gdisk`](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/) command to manually insert the partitions in to the MBR partition table. This is problematic, since an update from Apple can wipe this partitioning scheme. This may result in having to periodically reenter the partitioning information in to the MBR table via `gdisk`.